# Change the path where eclipse looks for plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I just renamed the directory where my eclipse was installed and i noticed that it was trying to look for plugins in c:\eclipse\plugins.. which is no longer the correct path. Can i change the path where eclipse looks for plugins?

I tried setting $ECLIPSE_HOME to my eclipse dir, setting -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/myeclipse/eclipse/plugins and -configuration C:/myeclipse/eclipse/plugins but none of them worked.

Let me explain the issue better with images. I set eclipse_home and i see the correct path ([screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/targetplatform.png/)) in the target platform. Problem is when i try to create a new web application using the GWT plugin its yet searching for plugins in c:\eclipse ([screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/pluginnotfound.png/)).

Cross posted [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/807360/#msg_807360)

Comment: does your eclipse instance launch?

Comment: Which plug-ins are you referring to, workspace or target platform?

Answer (score 1):

Goto Window->Preferences->Plugin Development->Target Platform.

Here edit the active platform to point to the proper directory of eclipse.

Comment: I have edited the question with screenshots to better explain the issue. Thanks